# DISEÑAR TABLA HTML EN CSS

Tags: php, html, css

me gustaria saber como puedo poner el estilo de esta imagen:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es mi código de mi tabla, esta en un archivo PHP:

```
   echo '<table>';
        echo '<tr>';
        echo '<th id="folio_usuario">ID de certificado:</th>';
        echo '<td>'. $respuesta['folio_usuario'] = $folio_usuario . '</td>';
        echo '</tr>';
        echo '<tr>';
        echo '<td>'. $respuesta['nombre'] = $nombre; '</td>';
        echo '<td>'. $respuesta['apellido'] = $apellido;'</td>';
        echo '<td> ha obtenido el curso </td>'; 
        echo '<td>'. $respuesta['curso'] = $curso;'</td>';
        echo '<td> en </td>';
        echo '<td>'. $respuesta['fecha'] = $fecha;'</td>';
        echo '</tr>';
```

O si me pudieran decir como hacerlo o como buscarlo por favor, trato de darle casi el mismo formato, pero realmente nunca he hecho algo asi y se me complica mucho, el estilo que le trato de hacer es en un CSS

Este es el poco código CSS que llevo a comparación de como me gustaria que se viera

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
}

:focus {
    outline: none;
}

body {
    background: #DBDBDB;
}

.formulario {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    width: 1100px;
    background: #fff;
    padding: 40px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    border-radius: 10px;
}
```

Comment: Realmente no llevo nada a comparación de la imagen que me gustaria que quedara, pero actualizo mi respuesta, espero su ayuda @BetaM

Comment: Porque usarias una tabla para imprimir el resultado? Sabes que hago yo, armo la maqueta con HTML y CSS, luego veo con PHP en que campos debo insertar registros, cuando necesito insertar datos dentro de un elemento estilo parrafo uso el elemento span, por si necesito estilizarlo con CSS

Comment: Estos recursos me ayudaron mucho al inicio: https://uniwebsidad.com/libros/xhtml, y https://uniwebsidad.com/libros/css